# email Validation on React native with tcomb package

Tags: react-native, validation

i want to validate email in react native, but it still didn't work for  me

this is my code

```
const Email = t.subtype(t.Str, (email) => {
  const reg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return reg.test(email);
});


componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    let data_cars = this.carOptions(newProps.cars);
    let data_year = this.yearCarOptions();
    if (Object.keys(newProps.car_brand).length && Object.keys(newProps.user).length) {
      let form = t.struct({
        name:  t.String,
        email: Email,
        phone: t.Number,
        plate: t.enums(data_cars),
        carbrand: t.enums(newProps.car_brand),
        carclass: t.enums(newProps.car_class),
        year: t.enums(data_year),
      })
      this.setState({ form })
      this.setState({ value: {
        name : newProps.user.name,
        email : newProps.user.email,
        phone : newProps.user.phone
      } });
    }
  }

const options = {
  auto: 'none',
  fields: {
    name: {
      label: 'Name',
      placeholder: 'name',
      placeholderTextColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
      error: 'enter your name'
    },
    email: {
      label: 'Email',
      placeholder: 'e.g: abc@gmail.com',
      placeholderTextColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
      error: 'Insert a valid email'
    },
  },
  stylesheet: formStyle.underline(colors.dark),
};
const Form = t.form.Form;
```

if i submitting the data, it could still return not an email

like this
[image]

how do i achieve to validate email?

Answer (score 0):

Use code like below

```
       validate = (text) => {
         console.log(text);
         let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (reg.test(text) === false) {
         console.log("Email is Not Correct");
         this.setState({ email: text })
     return false;
    }
 else {
    this.setState({ email: text })
   console.log("Email is Correct");
   }
 }
```

---

```
 <TextInput
    placeholder="Email ID"
    onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text)}
  value={this.state.email}
/>

 onPressOfButton = () => {
   this.validate(this.state.email);
 }
```